# What is $\arg(z)$ if $z=\left(1+i\sqrt3\right)^{2i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$z=(1+i\sqrt{3})^{2i}$, what is the respective $\arg(z)$? How do I calculate the exponent $2i$?

Answer (score 2):

You write
$$
z=\exp(2i\log(1+i\sqrt{3}))
$$
where you choose a branch of the logarithm. Since
$$
1+i\sqrt{3}=2e^{i\pi/3+2ki\pi}
$$
you have $\log(1+i\sqrt{3})=\log2+i\alpha$ (where $\alpha=\pi/3+2k\pi$).

Then we have
$$
2i\log(1+i\sqrt{3})=2i\log2-2\alpha
$$
and therefore
$$
\exp(2i\log(1+i\sqrt{3})=\exp(2i\log2-2\alpha)=e^{-2\alpha}e^{2i\log2}
$$
Thus the argument is $2\log2$. The modulus is not determined uniquely and depends on what branch of the logarithm you choose.

Comment: Is that $log $ natural logarithm?

Comment: @Aqua Yes, of course. Don't trust whoever tells you that the natural logarithm *must* be denoted differently.

Comment: ANd what does $ln$ stands for?

Comment: @Aqua Somebody uses it for the natural logarithm. But it's *not* a universal notation.

Comment: And why is $log$ better than $ln$ ?

Comment: @Aqua The notation "log" has been used for a few *centuries*. I feel no need to change it.

Comment: I don't force you to do anything, just asking. I like to know the motivation. Any way, does not $ln$ stands in latin for logaritmmus naturalis? It is interesting to me since you are in Italy.

Answer (score 0):

This exponentiation [is multivalued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Exponentiation). Since $1+i\sqrt{3}=e^{\ln 2+\pi i/3+2n\pi i}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, each such $n$ affords a choice $z=e^{2i\ln 2-2\pi/3-4n\pi}$ corresponding to one [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm) of $\ln z$.